# How to replace an OS if two OS (Windows10 and Ubunutu) are installed in a laptop (dual boot)?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, multi-boot, dualboot

I have two OS installed in my laptop. First installed one was Windows-10, later i installed Ubuntu as dual boot option. Now i want to replace the Ubuntu with Xbuntu, since it is lighter on resources. What are the steps to replace Ubuntu and install Xbuntu. while keeping Windows-10 functional. Laptop is 64 bit.

Comment: You can install the XFCE desktop environment on top of Ubuntu, switch to it permanently, and ditch (maybe) Gnome (if your Ubuntu is running Gnome), that would be the most painless option.

Comment: I was thinking yeah it's basically the same OS. If they wanted a fresh install at some point they could use reformat and install on the old Ubuntu partition.

Comment: Step1: make live usb with xubuntu. Step2: which partition is linux on? Step3: install xubuntu on linux partition. Q: how do your systems boot? Because it depends how to set up booting of the new linux.